# Randering Issue in firefox

Tags: php, facebook, firefox, redirect

`login.php` is my main page.

When user logged in, he redirected to `start.php`. On start.php I have `Logout` button.

When user click on his his facebook session terminates (i.e. logout) and redirected to login.php

`login.php` contains auto login code, means if user is already logged in then directly redirect to start.php.

So in `firefox`  when I click on `logout` button it redirects to login.php and again come back to start.php (behave like user is logged In) though we have logged out!

In case of `Chrome` it works as expected. When user clicks 'logout' button on `start.php` he redirected to `login.php` and this page persist.

This behavious of firefox is due to coockies stored in browser or anyother reason?

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/YCFpH/

Comment: Are you using $_SESSION variables?

Comment: @ilarsona: NO, I added to fiddle P.S.

Answer (score 0):

Not really my area so I could be way way off but can you use Set Cookie?  Do the cookies have to be deleted in the same parameters the were set with?  Is the setcookie value empty?  Again shot in the dark